# Using Java to create an outline of a square WITHOUT using shape class

Tags: java, eclipse, shapes

I am trying to create a square outline without using the shape class.  Basically due it with old fashion math.  I have one the creates a circle here:

```
public class CircleDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {
Display panel = new Display(10, 2);
drawCircle(panel);
}

public static void drawCircle(Display panel) {
int centerX = panel.getWidth() / 2;
int centerY = panel.getHeight() / 2;

// Draw a circle starting at the top and going clock wise
double degAng = 270;
double radius = 150;
double x, y, radAng;
while ( true ) {

    radAng = ( degAng * Math.PI ) / 180;
    x = centerX + radius * Math.cos ( radAng );
    y = centerY + radius * Math.sin ( radAng );
    panel.drawNextPixel ( (int) x, (int) y );
    degAng += 0.15;
    // System.out.println ( "x = " + x + ", y = " + y );
}

}
```

}

Comment: Can you not simply draw four connecting lines, with two originating at the top left of the square location and going as far as the length and width respectively?

Comment: If you're going to draw each pixel: have 4 loops that each draw one side of the square, pixel by pixel. General structure of such a loop would be: "Draw pixel, move pixel, repeat.". You would move to a different position according to the side of the square you're drawing.

Comment: `while (true)` will most likely block the event queue, preventing your programming from showing any updates...

Comment: You could also take a look at [this example](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/java/hoefer/), while it talks about curves, the basic idea is simular or even [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordcirclealgorithm.html).  Basically, the algorithm is actually about drawing lines from one point to another, based on a number of iterations...